# Are ROC curve calculations something that can be split up for parallel processing?

Tags: r

In R (or any other platform / language) is the calculation of a ROC curve something that can be split up and performed in parallel.  I'm doing one w/ 150k lines and it takes about 5-7 minutes for each calculation using the `pROC` package.  Any other suggestions for quicker AUC or ROC calculations would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The calculation of an ROC curve should be quite fast since it really just sorting results and calculating a cumulative sum of proportions, but my guess is that you are doing something more complex (or you are doing it in a very inefficient manner). This illustrates construction of an ROC curve for 15000 points ... almost instantanrous ( and doing it with 150K did slow it down a bit, but still under 2 seconds):

```
 testres <- data.frame(res=rnorm(15000), cat=rbinom(15000,1, .2))
 require(ROCR)
 pred <- prediction(testres$res, testres$cat)
 perf <- performance(pred,"tpr","fpr")
plot(perf)
```

Answer (score 0):

screechOwl. I am well aware that this post is from 6 years ago. I came across this when I was searching for more efficient method to compute AUC.

I have recently written a function that drastically reduces the time required to get the value of AUC, it also works with factors.

```
AUROC <- function(Target, Prediction){
  if(is.numeric(Prediction) == T){
    Order <- order(Prediction)
    Order <- Order[!Order %in% which(is.na(Prediction))]
    Prediction <- Prediction[Order]
    Target <- Target[Order]

    FP <- cumsum(!Target)/sum(!Target)
    TP <- cumsum(Target)/sum(Target)

    Repeated <- c(Prediction[-1] == Prediction[-length(Prediction)], FALSE)

    FP <- c(0, FP[!Repeated], 1)
    TP <- c(0, TP[!Repeated], 1)

    } else if(is.factor(Prediction) == T | is.character(Prediction) == T){

    DT1 <- data.table(Y = Target, X = Prediction)
    DT1 <- DT1[, list(Event = sum(Y),
                      `Non Event` = sum(!Y)),
               by = X]
    DT1[, Probability := Event / (Event + `Non Event`)]
    DT1 <- DT1[order(Probability), ]

    FP <- c(0, cumsum(DT1[, `Non Event`])/ sum(DT1[, `Non Event`]), 1)
    TP <- c(0, cumsum(DT1[, Event])/ sum(DT1[, Event]), 1)

    } 

    N <- length(FP)
    TP_avg <- (TP[-1] + TP[-N])/ 2
    FP_dif <- FP[-1] - FP[-N]

    Area <- sum(TP_avg * FP_dif)
    Results <- 0.5 + abs(Area - 0.5)
    return(Results)
}
```

However, I would say this is mostly the contribution of John Mount.
(http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/10/on-calculating-auc/)

The part that I have added is essentially the ability to deal with factors. Note that with some modifications in the last few lines, you can get this function to plot ROC curve. My findings show that this outperforms the method using prediction(), performance() and plot(), up until a few million rows or so, probably due to higher overheads. Beyond that point, it is better to stick with the method suggested  by "42-".

Hope this helps.